# Self processing page with sql and python

Tags: python, html, mysql

Im creating a shop page as my college project. I have a database set up and Im trying to use the select and submit to open a new page which will display information about the selected part. I just cant seem to be able to extract data from the database, can you help please ?

That's a part of my html

```
<p class="heading2">List of CPU's:</p>
<form action="show_part.py">
<select name="component">
    <option value="Intel_i7-5960x">Intel i7-5960x</option>
```

Then this is the python

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from cgitb import enable
import pymysql as db
from cgi import FieldStorage

print('Content-Type: text/html')
print()

form_data = FieldStorage()
component = form_data.getfirst("name")

result=''
try:
    connection = db.connect('***', '***', '***', '***')
    cursor = connection.cursor(db.cursors.DictCursor)
    result += cursor.execute("""SELECT price 
                                FROM components
                                WHERE name = %s""" % (component))
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
except db.Error:
result = '<p>Sorry! We are experiencing problems at the moment. Please call back later.</p>'

print("""
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Part details</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            %s
        </body>
        </html>""" % (result))
```

What happens is I keep getting the error message in the new page, meaning the code is fine, just something about the database query. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I cracked it, problem was in the sql query, where the program tried to execute:

```
SELECT price
FROM components
WHERE name=intel_i7-5960x
```

what is missing is **the quotes**:

```
SELECT price
FROM components
WHERE name='intel_i7-5960x'
```

so I changed that in my html file and it gets me not exactly where I want to go, but its a start !